# Push (Button) Switch Symbol

Tags: switches, symbol

I want to know what the symbol for a button switch is. It's the kind that if you push it, the circuit is complete, and if you release it, the circuit is broken. Also, it has four prongs, two on each side, which are connected in pairs. How do you draw this symbol in a diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an ordinary SPST NO pushbutton symbol:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2QnT6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit dependent on how you work with the EDA software you're using. If you prefer to show on the schematic exactly where each pin goes, you need four pins on the schematic to correspond to the four pins on the physical switch. Personally, I prefer to show this explicitly on the schematic, as here:

[image]

As to where it makes more of a difference, consider the bussed layout below from an [NKK datasheet](http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/JFnonilluminated.pdf).

[image]